# Display decimal number

Tags: c

somebody know how to represent the digits to the left of the decimal point?
I want to display the number 5 digits left to the point and 4 digits right to it/
for the exercise 12345/100 i want to get 00123.4500

Comment: Use `printf()` with a format string that specifies 10 character field width, leading zeroes, and 4 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Beware that the decimal number 123.45 does not exactly exist on a binary computer.  If you print using `%010.4f` you should get `00123.4500`, as requested.  But if you were to print it as `%.20f` you might see something like `123.4499969482421875` or `123.4500000000000028422` (depending on whether the number was saved as a `float` or a `double`).

Comment: @SteveSummit It is all about how numbers are represented. This touches one advantage of the fixed-point representation mentioned in my answer below. The OP does not specify that floating-point is used (even though I admit it is a fair assumption in this case).

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%010.4f", (double)12345/100);
```

`man 3 printf` says:

```
The overall syntax of a conversion specification is:

%[$][flags][width][.precision][length modifier]conversion
```

`.4` means the floating point *precision* to print 4 decimals.

`0` is a *flag* that means to pad with 0s.

`10` is the *width*.  If at the right of the decimal there are 4, and at the left there are 5, the total is 10 (with the dot).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%010.4f`? The field width is the whole number, not just before the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer of alinsoar is correct and the most common case, I would like to mention another possibility which sometimes is useful: fixed-point representation.

An `uint32_t` integer holds 9 decimal digits. We may choose to imagine a decimal point before the 4th digit from the right. The example would then look like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t a = 123450000;   // 12345.0000
    uint32_t b = a / 100;     //   123.4500
    uint32_t i = b / 10000;   // integer part
    uint32_t f = b % 10000;   // fractional part
    printf("%05" PRIu32 ".%04" PRIu32, i, f);  // 5 integer digits, 4 fractional digits 
}
```

Using fixed-point one has to pay special attention to the value range and e.g. multiplication needs special handling, but there are cases where it is preferable over the floating-point representation.